# Want to make a condition based on Friday

Tags: sql, postgresql, flyway

I use Flyway and  Postgres 
what i want is :

if today is `Friday`:

```
INSERT INTO APP(ID, DAY, NAME) VALUES (1, NOW() + INTERVAL '3 DAY', 'foo');
```

else

```
INSERT INTO APP(ID, DAY, NAME) VALUES (1, NOW() + INTERVAL '1 DAY', 'foo');
```

Comment: Okay.  You have the logic.  Use it in your application.  What is your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, how to write that (IF .. ELSE ...)? it's in an SQL file used by FlyWay.

Comment: Use a case expression in the VALUES clause.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `case when` expression

```
INSERT INTO APP(ID, DAY, NAME) 
    VALUES (1, case when to_char(NOW(), 'Dy')='Fri' then NOW() + INTERVAL '3 DAY' else NOW() + INTERVAL '1 DAY' end, 'foo')
```